# Excel VBA Group Chart Series Color

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program which will prompt user open file and generate line chart from the file data. The series will be plotted on the same chart. There will be two command buttons: one for user to choose file; another is used to generate chart. Every time the command button for chart is clicked, the series will be added based on the newly open file's data.

```
With ThisWorkbook.cht

For a = 1 To lastRow

' Add each series
    Set chtSeries = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    With chtSeries

        .Values = rng
        .XValues = Worksheets(sheet).Range(Worksheets(sheet).Cells(a, 1), Worksheets(sheet).Cells(a, 10))


    End With

    Next a

    End With
```

However, I need to group the series line whereby the lines from the same file represented by the same colour.

Comment: You should probably only call "Set chtSeries = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries" the first time, every other time, use a reference to the same series. Data points in the same series will have the same color.

Comment: I using loop to continuously create a new series because there will be more than 1 series in each file. For each row of the data, there will be a new series.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some detailed code that should help you :

```
Sub Graph()

Dim Gr As Chart

        Set Gr = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
            With Gr
            'Whole data source
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5)), PlotBy:=xlRows
            'Graph type
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
            'Place
            .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=NewSheetName
            'Title
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Chart Title"

            For a = 1 To 20
                'Data Series 1
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(a).Values = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 2), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5)) 'change with a
                .SeriesCollection(a).XValues = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 1)) 'not changing I think
                .SeriesCollection(a).AxisGroup = 1
                .SeriesCollection(a).Name = "MTTF"
                '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Weight = 1
                '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(int1 as integer, int1 as integer, int3 as integer) ' for a row/line
                '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(int1 as integer, int1 as integer, int3 as integer)
            Next a



            'Axis parameters
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Age"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Hours"
            .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDot
            .ChartArea.Font.Size = 14
            .Deselect
            End With

            'Legend positioning
            With ActiveChart.Legend
                .Left = 350
                .Top = 75
            End With
            'Drawing area positiong
            With ActiveChart.PlotArea
                .Width = 550
                .Height = 350
            End With



'Clean memory
Set Gr = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: Did it help you? Do you need something else?

Comment: The series will be in different colour. I need to open more than one file and plot them in only one chart. To differentiate the file data, I need the series line colour for each file to be the same. For example, line colour in "file 1" is shown in red colour while the series line colour in another file is shown in yellow.